# Trying to install pygame

Tags: python, netbeans, pygame

I've added the entry `C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pygame` at the end of my sys.path.

When I run the code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
```

I get the error: `ImportError: No module named locals`. But I can run this .py in C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\ANYFOLDER without error.

Also, if possible, I'd like to use this path in Netbeans. I've added the path in the Python platform manager in Netbeans but I get the same error as above.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Asker's own solution:

> Ok, I figured out that I can't name my file pygame.py otherwise it
>   will try to import itself(?).
>
> Same with Netbeans. Absolutely nothing (projects, folders, etc)
>   can be named "pygame".

Comment: this is because, python looks first in the current directory for importing modules, then in the install path. You also shouldn't name files like other modules.